# Looping SQL queries from Entity Framework returns the first row when multiple SQL keys

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

I have a strange problem that I never experienced before using EF Core.

```
VismaContext vc = new VismaContext(Cfg.VismaCS);
List<OrdDocLn> list = vc.OrdDocLn.Where(x => x.OrdDocNo == 1333).ToList();
foreach (OrdDocLn o in list) {
    Log.Information($"{o.DocLnNo} {o.Price}");
}
```

that returns this

[image]

but when I query in sql I get this

[image]

So the foreach loop is listing all the lines but show the values from the first line for all lines

The model look like this

[image]

I am using Visual Studio 2022 and EF Core 6 and MSSQL

The table in SQL has two keys, OrdDocNo and DocLnNo and I suspect this need to be setup somehow in DbContext but I can't figure out how to do it.

This is the DbContext

[image]

This is the table in SQL

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I need to specify the keys in the DBContext

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Entity<OrdDocLn>().HasKey(c => new { c.OrdDocNo, c.DocLnNo });
}
```

Comment: Just writing same answer for you ;)